# On Spec of a localized ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-schemes

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with unity, and $S$ a regular multiplicative subset of $A$ containing $1$. I know that given $f \in A$, Spec $A_f$ corresponds to an open subscheme of Spec $A$. I was wondering does Spec $S^{-1}A$ also correspond to an open subscheme of Spec $A$ as well (for any multiplicative subset $S$)? Thank you!

PS I guess what I am curious is that: when I consider the subset of Spec $A$ that does not meet $S$, is it isomorphic to Spec $S^{-1}A$ as schemes?

Comment: It corresponds to the set of points $x$ of the spectrum of $A$ such that $\mathfrak{p}\cap S = \varnothing$. To be isomorphic to the spectrum of $S^{-1} A$, it should be locally closed. Do you think it is in general ?

Comment: @RobertGreen ...I guess not? but would they be the same as topological spaces by any chance?

Comment: Wrong ;-) See my answer.

Comment: Oooops! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Bourbaki, *Algèbre Commmutative*, chapter II, paragraph 4, number 3, corollary of the proposition 13, the morphism of schemes $\textrm{Spec}(S^{-1} A)\to \textrm{Spec}(A)$ corresponding to the localisation map $A\to S^{-1} A$ induces an homeomorphism of $\textrm{Spec}(S^{-1} A)$ onto the subset of $\textrm{Spec}(A)$ consisting in points $x$ of $A$ such that $\mathfrak{p}_x \cap S = \varnothing$.

You can also see Grothendieck's *Eléments de géométrie algébrique*, I, corollaire 1.2.6. which results from the more general corollaire 1.2.4. Let me detail the latter.

**corollaire 1.2.4.** Let $\varphi : A' \to A$ a ring morphism such that each $f\in A$ can be written $f = h \varphi(f')$ for some $h\in A^{\times}$ and $f'\in A'$. Then on the spectra $\varphi$ induces an homeomorphism from $X = \textrm{Spec}(A)$ to its image.

*Proof.* Let's show that for each $P\subseteq A$ we can find a $P'\subseteq A'$ such that $V(E) = V(\varphi(E'))$. As $X$ is a $T_0$ topological space this will imply that the induced map is injective and is an homeomorphism, thanks to fact that ${\psi}^{-1}(V(E')) = V(\varphi(E'))$ where $\psi$ is the scheme morphism induced by $\varphi$. But for any $f \in E$ just take any $f'\in A'$ such that $f = h \varphi(f')$ for some $h\in A^{\times}$ (possible by hypothesis) and take $E'$ the set of such $f'$'s. $\square$

Note that a surjective $\varphi$ satisfies the hypothesis of this corollary. And that the localisation map $A\to S^{-1} A$ also satisfies it, giving an answer to your question.

Comment: I just have one question. So Spec $S^{-1}A$ is a closed subscheme of Spec $A$. But when $S = \{1, f, f^2, ... \}$, Spec $S^{-1}A$ is an open subscheme... Does it mean Spec $A_f$ is open and closed?

Comment: No, I went too far, corrected my answer. Your point is good, with localization wrt powers of $f$, you can indeed find an counter-example to closedness of (the image of) $\textrm{Spec}(S^{-1} A)$ in $\textrm{Spec}(A)$. Typically $\mathbf{A}_{k}^1 \backslash\{0\}$ for a field $k$.